# how do i make a custom object name field with a lookup relationship

Tags: custom-field, lookup

I have a custom object - responses. I want the name field to have a lookup relationship with the contacts object. Is this possible?

Comment: It can be possible using code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking if the standard 'Name' field that is part of a new object can be a lookup field?  Then then the answer is 'no'.  Name is a required and standard field that can only be a text field or an autonumber.

However, there are several options you can use to work around it.

1)  A workflow rule to update the Name, with the same string as the related record's name (recommended).

2)  Use autonumber on the name, remove it from the layout, and add a custom name field in place of the lookup.  You won't be able to use the name field in related lists as well, but it's an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula 'text' field using the 'hyperlink' function to create a pseudo lookup. Here's a quick example using case/contact:

```
HYPERLINK(ContactId, "Contact Link")
```

Hyperlink assumes the / so you don't have to do "/" & ContactId.